# How to represent 'if (condition1 && condition2)' in sequence diagram

Tags: if-statement, uml, sequence-diagram

I know `alt` is the equivalent of `if else` in UML, but how to represent a more complex condition like:

```
if (condition1 && condition2) else condition3
```

Is it `[condition1 == true]&&[condition2==true]` ?

Answer (score 0):

The guard in the operand of a combined fragment such as `alt` is an interaction constraint expressed between a pair of square brackets. Therefore, your condition should stay between one pair of brackets.

UML offers full flexibility about how to specify such a constraint:

> The specification of a user-defined Constraint is often expressed as a text string in some language, whose syntax and interpretation is as defined by that language. In some situations, a formal language (such as OCL) or a programming language (such as Java) may be appropriate, in other situations natural language may be used.

In other words, with the guard brackets `[condition1 && condition2]` is perfectly fine. If you prefer [OCL syntax](http://www-sop.inria.fr/members/Charles.Andre/CAdoc/ESINSA/UMLOCL-memo.pdf), it would be `[condition1 and condition2]`.